# SFTP-server uploaded files having wrong rights

Tags: linux, ssh, file-permissions, sftp, umask

I have been trying to figure out what is wrong with the file rights. When I am uploading files using FileZilla all the files get rights -rw-r--r--. I would want them to have -rwxr-xr-x. I have tried using umask to fix the rights but something is wrong. I have read that you could change the rights with umask like this for example:

In /etc/ssh/sshd_config, change the following:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -u 002
```

With this change I am getting files with -rw-rw-r--. As far as I know 0 should give all rights? But I am getting rw only.

Whats wrong? I am using Debian.

Comment: try 0002 instead of 002.

Comment: That also results in -rw-rw-r--

Comment: just remember... two rights don't make a wrong

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If an SFTP client does not specify permissions for uploaded files, the OpenSSH SFTP server assigns 0666 permissions to newly created files (minus the umask 0002 makes the 0664).

This is hard-coded, you cannot change it. See the `process_open()` function in the `sftp-server.c` of OpenSSH. And even, if this was not specified explicitly, the 0666 is still the *nix default for files, you cannot just change this with umask (that's true in general, not just for OpenSSH).

See also [Does OpenSSH SFTP server use umask or preserve client side permissions after put command (chrooted environment)?](https://serverfault.com/q/639042/168875)

*Note that your umask is actually wrong. If you want 0644, use umask 0022, not 0002.*

The FileZilla never specifies permissions for uploaded files. What results in the behavior you are experiencing.

---

To achieve your desired permissions:

- With FileZilla you can change the file permissions only manually, after the upload, using *File permissions* command from a remote file context menu.

  [image: Changing permissions in FileZilla]
- Use an SFTP client that allows specifying the permissions for the uploaded files.

  For example WinSCP allows that.

  See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_transfer_custom

  [image: Setting permissions for uploaded files in WinSCP]

  *(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: I switched to WinSCP and did as you instructed and now everything works.