# SFTP clients not respecting default UMASK permissions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, sftp, umask

Here's my situation: I'm setting up an Ubuntu 14.04 web server for a team to share. I'd like the team to have read/write access to everything inside `var/www/html` (same as `CHMOD 775` on every file and folder).

My issue is that SFTP clients on the Mac (Transmit, Cyberduck, and FileZilla) don't respect the default permissions I've set up.

After several hours, I've walked through many steps to accomplish my goal:

**Set up team permissions:**

1. Created a `myteam` group
2. Added all users to the `myteam` group
3. Changed the group ownership of `/var/www/html` to `myteam`

At this point, `ls -la` of `/var/www` returns

`drwxrwsr-x  2 marcelo myteam 4096 Jul 20 13:29 html`

**Set a default UMASK:**

1. Updated `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` with `Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -u 002` based on [this article](http://jeff.robbins.ws/articles/setting-the-umask-for-sftp-transactions).
2. Updated `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and `/etc/pam.d/login` with a new line `session    optional     pam_umask.so umask=0027` based on [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/228396/how-to-setup-sshs-umask-for-all-type-of-connections)
3. Updated `/etc/pam.d/common-session/` with a new line `session optional pam_umask.so` and edited `/etc/login.defs` to change the UMASK line to `UMASK 002` based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220531/how-to-set-system-wide-umask)
4. Rebooted all appropraite services and/or rebooted the entire machine

At this point, if I SSH into the server via a shell, the `umask` command reports `002`, and all new files and folders have the correct permissions. However, if I SFTP into the server via Transmit, Filezilla, Cyberduck, etc. and create files or folders, it does not respect and defaults files to `rw-r--r--` and folders to `rwxrwsr-x` (the folders are correct). I checked, and the FTP clients are not overriding any permissions - those are disabled.

Comment: `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` The correct file to update is sshd_config, not ssh_config. Please confirm which file you updated. Beyond that, enable logging in sftp-server (read the sftp-server man page) and check the log to see if clients are explicitly setting file permissions on the files they create.

Comment: @Kenster - I was editing `sshd_config`, so it was a typo. SFTP logs are showing `open "/var/www/html/untitled file" flags WRITE,CREATE,TRUNCATE mode 0644` when using Transmit, so it looks like the client is setting it?

Comment: @Kenster - Tried out using plain SCP, and it still uploads with 644 permissions. I'm wondering if it maintains the permissions of the file on my machine when I upload.

Comment: After some more digging, it looks like files are simply maintaining their source permissions from my local machine. Whether I upload them via an SFTP like Transmit, SCP, rsync, or grunt-sftp, they all keep the local permissions. Not sure where to go with this...

Comment: See [Does OPENSSH SFTP server uses umask or preserve client side permissions after put command?](http://serverfault.com/q/639042/168875)

Answer (score 1):

This is evergreen problem and it was discussed many times. I wrote short answer here:

https://superuser.com/questions/937003/setting-default-group-permissions-via-sftp/937735#937735

Basically you answered yourself using your last comment. SFTP preserves original permissions and truncates `umask` from it.

Comment: Thanks - so is the only way around this to use the a less secure FTP system like vsftp and set default permissions through that? [It seems like vsftp lets you set up default umask settings](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1570700), although I haven't tested this yet.

Comment: I have never tried `vsftp`, but the problem is not with setting `umask`, but with the understanding the behaviour of SFTP and umask.

Comment: I understand the behavior now after reading through the references in the comments. My question now would be what the best way is to solve my issue? I need multiple users able to upload to a directory where the entire group has read/write privileges. vsftpd seems to have solved it, but I'd still like something more secure and modern like SFTP/SCP.

Comment: You can also setup VSFTPD to use SSL and gain more security using FTPS, probably even better then using SSH, since you don't have to verify fingerprints and your certificate is signed with some certificate authority, similar or the same as you have for HTTPS.