# Files uploaded using SFTP does not have the correct rights

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, shell, sftp

I have a weird issue when trying to upload files to a server using SFTP.

When for maximum security I use a user with a disabled shell ("/bin/false") to upload files, I get mode 640 for the uploaded files and this is not what I want (local files have mode 664).

However when I enable the shell "/bin/bash" for the same user I get the correct mode, 664.

I am not sure to understand what is happening here, why does disabling shell change the mode of the uploaded files?

My sshd configuration:

```
Port 22
Protocol 2
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
UsePAM yes
UseDNS no
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

Comment: I suspect a valid shell is required for the client to execute "chmod" after uploading.
Can't this be a solution? https://serverfault.com/q/283492/56333

Comment: You should check what happens in the rc files of your system... ~/.bashrc , ~/.bash_profile, /etc/profile, /etc/profile.d

Comment: is using `rsync -a` an option?  On older systems, you have to tell rsync to use ssh, `rsync -a -e ssh`

Comment: You said you tried the solution provided by @ivanivan, can you provide your sshd_config with his fix applied?

Comment: Try to set the setuid bit on your folder to which you upload you files.
https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Directory-Setuid-and-Setgid.html#Directory-Setuid-and-Setgid

Answer (score 3):

By not having a valid shell, the system default umask isn't being applied/used.

What you can do is put your users in a group, and force a few things via the `/etc/sshd_config` file, including a umask -

```
Match Group uploadusers
  ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 0002
```

the `-u 0002` option sets a umask for the internal-sftp program/subsystem and any files uploaded through it IF the user is a member of the `uploadusers` group.

Personally I also `chroot` the users so that they can only access their directories - check the `ChrootDirectory` option as it applies to a `Match Group` directive in the `sshd_config` file.

Comment: I have tired this but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this is because when a shell is getting involved, a UMASK is being applied. In your case, it's likely (for bash), being applied inside of /etc/bashrc (this is assuming some modern Red Hat/Centos 7 version), location of these files might vary.
When using nothing, check the UMASK setting in /etc/profile maybe.